# rm command in bash script does not work with variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, rm, variable

I am doing a bash script to create a back-up of my mysql databases.
Actually, I would like to delete the old ones.

So, I create my script with variable for maintability.

The whole script is actually working, the only one thing who does not work, is the delete of the old ones. I was thinking it would be the easiest part.

Anyway, here is my code, can someone telle me what's wrong ?
And the rm command returns me : `rm: impossible de supprimer « /path/to/backup/files/*.gz »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type` Which means `rm: impossible to delete  « /path/to/backup/files/*.gz »: no files or directory of this type`

But what is really strange, first is that [I found the script in a tutorial](http://danieldvork.in/script-for-mysql-backup-to-dropbox/)

Two, that if I launch myself the "rm /path/to/backup/files/*.gz" in a shell command, this is working and deleting all the .gz files (as excpected)

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="***"
PASSWORD="****"
OUTPUT="/path/to/backup/files"

rm "$OUTPUT/*.gz"

databases=`mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do
    if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] && [[ "$db" != "performance_schema" ]] ; then
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump --force --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $db > $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
        gzip $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
    fi
done
```

Thank you,

Comment: try `rm -rf "path"`

Comment: of course, this is not working. Option r is used of recursif (I dont want recursif, I want *, the wildcard, and is used to force)

Comment: try 

   `rm "$OUTPUT"/*.gz`

Comment: The quotes in your `rm` command were preventing the expansion of the "*.gz" part; just quote $OUTPUT -> `rm "$OUTPUT"/*.gz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way is to combine rm with find and/or xargs .
These are some alternatives:

```
find "$output" -name *.gz -type f -delete
find "$output" -name "*.gz" -type f -exec rm '{}' \;
find "$output" -name *.gz -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

PS: type f means to find for files.

By default find searches all subdirs. You can limit the find operation to the current directory if required by using maxdepth option:

```
find "$output" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.gz" -type f -exec rm '{}' \;
```

If you need to keep working with rm and a variable, this worked for me in one line:

```
out="/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appsfiles";rm "$out"/*.txt
rm: remove regular file '/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appsfiles/a.txt'? y
rm: remove regular file '/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appsfiles/a ver 1.txt'? y
rm: remove regular file '/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appsfiles/b.txt'? y
rm: remove regular file '/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appsfiles/c.txt'? y
rm: remove regular file '/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/appsfiles/d.txt'? y
```

Comment: I have tried to add some slash at the end of my OUTPUT variable. This was not working, anyway the first find command works so thank you.
I should think by myself to use find, but I am still confused with -exec (sometimes {}, sometimes [], sometimes \ ...)

Comment: `rm` works just fine with variables, actually

Comment: `rm $out/*.txt` will give you unpleasant surprises if there are spaces in `$out`.

Answer (score 19):

The

```
rm "$OUTPUT/*.gz"
```

shell command line tells the shell to execute `/bin/rm` with with two arguments: `rm` and `/path/to/backup/files/*.gz`.

The space, `"` and `$` are special characters in the shell language syntax. Space is used to delimit command arguments, `"` is used to quote other special characters (not all, `$` for instance is still special) like that `*` above, and `$` is used for some expansions (like the `$OUTPUT` parameter expansion that you're using here).

`rm` once started will try to remove that `/path/to/backup/files/*.gz` file. If that file doesn't exist (as is the case for you), it will report an error.

When you write:

```
rm /path/to/backup/files/*.gz
```

or

```
rm "$OUTPUT"/*.gz
```

Since `*` is not quoted this time, it triggers another special feature of the shell called globbing or filename generation or filename expansion. The shell tries to expand the word that contains that `*` character to the list of file names that match the pattern.

So if `/path/to/backup/files` contains a `a.gz` and `b.gz` files, the shell will actually call `rm` with 3 arguments: `rm`, `/path/to/backup/files/a.gz` and `/path/to/backup/files/b.gz` which looks more like what you want here.

Note that `$OUTPUT` itself still needs to be quoted as otherwise it could end up being split if it contains characters of `$IFS` or also be subject to globbing if it contained any wildcard characters (like that `*` above).

It's also a good idea to get used to writing:

```
rm -- "$OUTPUT"/*.gz
```

Here `$OUTPUT` happens to start with `/`, so it's fine, but the day you change `$OUTPUT` to `-foo-` for instance, it will stop working as that `-foo-/...` would be taken by `rm` as options.

If the script is not meant to be interactive, you may want to add the `-f` option to `rm`. That will disable all user prompts, and remove the error if there's no matching file (most shells, when a glob has no match, pass the pattern as-is to the application, and `rm -f` doesn't complain when asked to remove a file that doesn't exist in the first place).

Comment: To summarize: Only the variable needs to be quoted. Quoting the `*` stops it from globbing.

Answer (score -2):

Try to get those files and then delete them:

```
ARCS=`ls $OUTPUT | grep "\.gz$"`

for _arch in $ARCS; do
    rm -f $_arch
done
```

Comment: Please, try your code dude!
This is full of errors, that I try to solve, but anyway this is not working.
Actually, your _arch variable as "ARCS" value! GG

Comment: `rm: missing operand`

Comment: @vekah edited my answer; fixed typos ;)

Comment: [Why not to parse ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).